# Confused about differential form

Tags: calculus, differential-forms

I have only taken one calculus course in my life so please bear with me.
I came across this equation in a paper:

dt = dz/u + d[f(y)]

It looks like Leibniz-notation, but taken apart. My friend told me it's called "differential form". However, it doesn't make sense to me that dt would be something in and of itself. Same goes for dz. An actual infinitesimal difference doesn't really exist, right? Could anyone explain to me what an equation like this is supposed to mean or signify?

Edit: I don't necessarily want a formal definition. Just an intuitive understanding.

Edit 2:

[image]

Comment: Have you googled "diferential forms"? Are you familiar with the definition of a vector space? how about linear maps?

Comment: I have googled that term, but unfortunately I still couldn't understand it. I know what a vector space is, but not what a linear map is.

Comment: If you know something about tangent spaces to a manifold I could help you

Comment: In general, given a functon $f\in\mathcal C^{\infty}(M)$, you define the differential as the $1$-form such that $$df\vert_p(v)=v(f),\forall v\in T_pM.$$A smooth 1-form is a smooth section of the cotangent bundle defined as a map $\omega:M\to T^*M$, $\omega\in\mathcal C^{\infty}(M)$ and $\pi\circ\omega=id_M.$

Comment: If you know what a vector space is but not what a linear map is, then you should instead focus on studying linear algebra first. Because (multivariable) calculus is HIGHLY based on linear algebra. Anyway here's a [previous answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4138085/568204) (see also the link there), which is about as simple as I can explain it. But again, without even a basic understanding of linear algebra, these concepts are impossible to explain properly.

Comment: The whole $dx$ and $dy$ thing are essentially notation that are meant to capture an extremely small area unit. Differential forms are confusing to advanced undergraduates, so I think most honest thing I can say that will be effective is that forms are an alternative way of looking at integration that has some advantages over standard integration, but some disadvantages as well.